# How to create a blurry to non-blurry animation

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create a magnifying glass type effect in my iPhone app, where the text goes from blurry to not blurry in an animation.  Can anyone think of a way to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6 we finally have the ability to make an image literally blurry, using a CIFilter. So you could, if you really wanted to, make an image of the area to be blurred, blur it with CIFilter, and superimpose that blurred image. Then you could use a timer or CADisplayLink to ask for successive "frames" of the animation, and each time you would do the same thing, only creating a less and less blurred image and showing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, we want the app to also run under iOS 5.

Comment: Then pick a CIFilter that does exist in iOS 5. It won't be as true a blur, but it might do.

Answer (score 0):

It is Loupe effect.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // here we're just doing some transforms on the view we're magnifying,
    // and rendering that view directly into this view,
    // rather than the previous method of copying an image.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,1*(self.frame.size.width*0.5),1*(self.frame.size.height*0.5));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.5, 1.5);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,-1*(touchPoint.x),-1*(touchPoint.y));
    [self.viewToMagnify.layer renderInContext:context];
}
```

Reference: http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/03/a-simpler-magnifying-glass-loupe-view-for-the-iphone

Comment: This does a good job of magnifying an image, but that is not what I need to do.